# Some problems in group theory

Tags: finite-groups, proof-verification

May I know if my proof/solution is correct? Thank you v. much.

1.) If $G, H$ are finite groups of order $10$ and $21$ respectively, then every homomorphism $f:G \to H$ satisfies $f[G] = \{e_H\}.$

Proof: 
Given $g \in G-\{e_G\}, \ o(g) =  2, 5 \ or  \ 10.$ Suppose $f(g) \neq e_H.$ Then, $o(f(g))= 3,7  \ or \ 21.$

$o(g) =2 \implies (f(g))^2=e_H \implies 2|21.$ (Contradiction)

$o(g)=5 \implies (f(g))^5 = e_H \implies o(f(g))|5.$ (Contradiction)

$o(g)=10 \implies (f(g))^{10} = e_H \implies o(f(g))|10.$ (Contradiction)

2.) Let $g=(12)(123)(12345) \in S_5.$ Express $g^{222}$ as product of disjoint cycles.

Solution: $g = (1345) \implies o(g) = 4 \implies g^{222}=g^2 = (14)(35).$

Comment: It looks mostly correct.  In question 1, the way you handled the case $o(g) = 2$ is great.  Why not repeat that for the other cases?

Comment: Can you state and prove the general result, where the two groups have relatively prime order?  This will get you away from the case-by-case approach and force you to think about what all the cases have in common.

Comment: By the way, your solution to question 2 is correct.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Consider any homomorphism $f:H \to K,$ where $\gcd (|H|, |K|) = 1$ 


Given $g \in H -\{e_{H}\}, o(f(g))= m $ and $ m |  \ |K|.$  Since $(f(g))^m =e_K, \ o(f(g))|m,$ hence $\gcd(|H|,|K|) \geq m.$ So, $m$ is necessarily $1.$

Comment: @SammyBlack: On a lighter note, your profile description seems interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first proof is fine. Alternately, you can mention that for all $g\in G,$ and any homomorphism $f:G\to H,$ we must have $o(g)\mid 10$ and $o\bigl(f(g)\bigr)\mid 21,$ but since $$f(g)^{o(g)}=f\left(g^{o(g)}\right)=f(e_G)=e_H,$$ then we must have $o\bigl(f(g)\bigr)\mid o(g),$ and so $o\bigl(f(g)\bigr)\mid 10.$ The only positive common factor of $10$ and $21$ is $1,$ so $o\bigl(f(g)\bigr)=1$ for all $g\in G$ and all homomorphisms $f:G\to H,$ meaning the only homomorphism $G\to H$ is the map $g\mapsto e_H.$ This (non-casewise) argument allows us to easily generalize to the result that if $G$ and $H$ are finite groups with relatively prime orders, then the only homomorphism $G\to H$ is the map $g\mapsto e_H.$

Your second proof also looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good -- well done!